# Burning vegetable oil as fuel

Tags: organic-chemistry

I heard just recently that vegetable oil (i.e palm oil) does burn.

I am also aware that burning used motor/engine oil, does emit hazardous gases such as nitro or sulfur oxide, hence prohibited by government.

How about burning used cooking oil?

I am not saying convert them first to methyl ester, but straight put them directly on a burner/fire. What gases do they emit and is it harmful too?

Comment: There is a good reason why vegetable oils are usually converted to esters before use as a fuel. The resulting compounds are *far* more similar to existing diesel and can be used *without* substantial adjustments to the engines (and fuel pumps) required to compensate for different physical and chemical properties.

Comment: By "fuel", do you mean as in for an internal combustion engine, or for cooking, or for light, or what?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer: with technical adjustments, it is possible (cf. e.g., [Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vegetable_oil_fuel)).

Note, the levels of sulfur in modern gas/petrol are low; for one, to limit the generation of sulfur oxides during the combustion (e.g., $\ce{SO2}$) contributing to [*acid rain*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid_rain).  However, desulfurization equally is economically interesting to access sulfur which is used *as such* for [vulcanization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulcanization), or the controlled combustion to yield $\ce{SO3}$ and eventually sulfuric acid.  One of the commonly known processes of desulfurization is the [Claus process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claus_process).

The potential problem with burning used cooking oil is its chemical composition.  Like gas/petrol for a car, vegetable oil is *a blend of chemicals*.  Gas/petrol mainly consists of hydrocarbons (compounds only consisting of carbon and hydrogen) and some additives (like methyl *tert*-butyl ether ([MTBE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methyl_tert-butyl_ether) or/and methyl *tert*-butyl ether ([ETBE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethyl_tert-butyl_ether))):

[image]

(image credit to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gasoline))

Vegetable oils, on the other hand, are *esters* of glycerol. Because each of the three hydroxyl groups may be esterified differently, the chemical composition of the oil however may vary much more (*plus* effects by season of harvest/how it is processed lining up for their use e.g., in the kitchen):

[image]

(image credit to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triglyceride))

In comparison to molecules in gas/petrol for a car, the molecules in vegetable oils tend to consist of a larger number of atoms per molecule. This and aforementioned greater variability of chemical composition of vegetable oil *requires an adjustment* of the air intake during the combustion to yield an exhaustive combustion while reducing the generation of nitrogen oxides and [soot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soot).  (Some of the later passes the exhaust pipe, some may deposit next and on the burner/oil atomizer nozzle.)  It has been possible for long time (e.g., [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P2_0EhPWO50) about an old omnivore combustion engine) and vegetable oils seem to attract again interest (cf. e.g., [Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vegetable_oil_fuel)) to contribute as a form of energy.  Technology aside, it equally is a topic of discussion to balance production of e.g., canola/oilseed for food *vs.* combustion.